# Decrypting a cipher in AES 128 Counter Mode

Tags: python, aes

In this exercise I shall find out a flag based on my username (vdeppe in this case). The code I have got is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter


def encrypt(msg):
    nonce = os.urandom(16)
    key = os.urandom(32)
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=lambda: nonce)
    return aes.encrypt(msg)

Plaintext:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: its-exercise.cs.upb.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: flag=**FLAG_REDACTED**
Please input your username
> vdeppe
Ciphertext:
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
```

That was pregiven by the exercise. When I type my username (vdeppe) then the ciphertext as above is the output. Is there any possibility how I get the flag, which bases on my username? The only information I have, that it is based on aes128 with counter mode and the following description:
I found out how messages to https://its-exercise.cs.upb.de were encrypted before they fixed their vulnerability and implemented a server that reproduces that. You can find the vulnerability as well as an option to encrypt messages with their method below. Use the command given under Access Point in a Linux Terminal for further steps.

Access Point    Status (last updated on)

nc its-exercise.cs.upb.de 1337
    N/A

I already tried this, but doesn't work at all and I have absolutely no idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter

def encrypt(msg):
    nonce = os.urandom(16)
    key = os.urandom(32)
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=lambda: nonce)
    ass = aes
    return aes.encrypt(msg)

chiffre = encrypt("vdeppe")
print(chiffre)

def decrypt(msg):
    return aes.decrypt(msg)

print(decrypt(chiffre))
```

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I find out the flag, which is hidden and bases on my username? I guess, I have to decrypt the ciphertext, which outputs when I input my username vdeppe. But no idea how to solve this